# Create a "New" button that creates 3 UI text fields in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am building an app in Xcode using Swift.

I am trying to create a button "New" that each time the user presses it, it will automatically create 3 UI textfield boxes

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `UITableView`, when the button is pressed call `addRow()`, have a cell setup with your `UITextField` or add them programmatically. I presumed you are using Storyboards and not SwiftUI.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var count = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any) { // Link this to the button on the storyboard
         count += 3
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return count
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellID", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell //OR you could create this programmatically
        
/*
        let textFld = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UITextField // don't forget to set this in storyboard!
        textFld.placeholder = "\(indexPath.row)"
        
*/
        return cell
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

TableView is a very good option, because it handles automatically the position of cells and let you create any number of fields.

Just for information, you could also create directly UITextField. Create an array of UITextFields that you will populate. You will have to take care of scrolling if too many textFields…
I assume you draw each under the other

```
 // In viewDidLoad, not in the button's action
var textFields : [UITextField] = []  
var nbOfTF = 0

// In IBAction
for i in 0..<3 { 
    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 40 + (nbOfTF+i) *40, width: 45, height: 40))
    textFields.append(textField)
    self.view.addSubview(textField)
    nbOfTF += 1
}
```